# Calculating the Percentage of Divergence and Identifying Divergent Points in 2D Motion Analysis using Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have two objects performing similar motions in a 2D space. Each object has the same size and number of points, and the duration of their motion is equal. To analyze their motion, I have access to a 3-dimensional array with the following structure:

- Dimension 1: Represents the frames of the motion (n frames).
- Dimension 2: Represents the points that make up the objects (n
  points).
- Dimension 3: Contains the X and Y coordinates of each point.

However, I've observed that the points of one object may not move in the same way as the corresponding points of the other object. I would like to calculate the overall percentage of divergence between the two motions and identify which points diverge the most.

Here is an animated plot using matplotlib of the objects.
[image]

Both the motion 1 and the motion 2 seem pretty similar however they are not the same. The first one is considered to be the correct movement and the second one the divergent one.

Example of input:

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (52, 33, 2)        
strides:  (528, 16, 8)     
itemsize:  8
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0x1bf69766e00
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: float64

[[[0.13391721 0.66876662] 
  [0.11917165 0.65657735] 
  [0.12027034 0.65444827] 
  ...
  [0.9269594  0.79895139] 
  [0.90251642 0.88351011] 
  [0.88661313 0.86612344]]

 [[0.13308156 0.66942436] 
  [0.11864304 0.65675116] 
  [0.11973081 0.65454942] 
  ...
  [0.92505908 0.79896438]
  [0.90405625 0.88353145]
  [0.8865965  0.86615652]]

 [[0.13308156 0.66942436]
  [0.11864304 0.65675116]
  [0.11973081 0.65454942]
  ...
  [0.92505908 0.79896438]
  [0.90405625 0.88353145]
  [0.8865965  0.86615652]]

 ...

 [[0.13486739 0.67316931]
  [0.12051648 0.66134679]
  [0.12145752 0.65935892]
  ...
  [0.90726781 0.79713285]
  [0.90906012 0.88699126]
  [0.87629938 0.86243683]]

 [[0.13486739 0.67316931]
  [0.12051648 0.66134679]
  [0.12145752 0.65935892]
  ...
  [0.90726781 0.79713285]
  [0.90906012 0.88699126]
  [0.87629938 0.86243683]]

 [[0.13486739 0.67316931]
  [0.12051648 0.66134679]
  [0.12145752 0.65935892]
  ...
  [0.90726781 0.79713285]
  [0.90906012 0.88699126]
  [0.87629938 0.86243683]]]
```

Could you please provide guidance on how to approach this problem in Python? Specifically, I'm looking for suggestions on the algorithm or methods that could be used to calculate the percentage of divergence and determine the most divergent points.

EDIT: I tried using SciPy's cdist for each frame and then calculate the mean dist, however I couldn't get much out of the results since the mean distance of every second input compared against the same first input had almost the same resulting value. Which is impossible since some movements were almost the exact same and some others were really different.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76690111/edit) your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [full text of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), all as formatted text in the question itself. Do not post images of text. The code should be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did't ask for a tutorial. I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to approach the solution of this problem. I asked fo guidance. Any papers, links or references are highly appreciated. I can provide an example of the input if that is required however the format of the input is mentioned. If Stack Overflow isn't the right service then could you redirect me to the right stack exchange page? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little vague (what does percentage of divergence actually mean?) but other relevant sites might include [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for a statistical approach or possibly [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) for an algorithmic approach.

Comment: You are right. Sometime I forget that others don't have direct access to the information I have. Let me refactor my question.

Answer (score 0):

i don't really understand the structure of the objects you are working with, but the only thing that comes to my mind is to calculate the coefficient of determination(aka r) (or the adjusted coefficient of determination), so for each point you will be calculating r_x and r_y and do the sum for each frame, you will end up with (r_x,r_y) for each point, the points that have r_x and r_y close to 1 and the good points "that do not have a lot of divergence.

Comment: I added an input example also I have provided a gif with the motion of the objects (which are pretty much human skeletons).